# Magento 2 Mailchimp Guest customer fields are not sync on Mailchimp after order placed

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, customer, mailchimp

Magento 2 Mailchimp Guest customer fields are not synced with Mailchimp after the order is placed.

We are using Magento 2.4.5-p1 version and the Mailchimp version is 103.4.50

Except for Guest email other fields are not synced for Guest customers.

Fields like First Name, Last Name etc... should be shown resync for Guest customers

Register customer fields are synced.